# "There is no connected camera" - Macbook Pro 13" 2017

Tags: camera, webcam

Does anybody have any alternative solutions? Seems like my computer no longer detect my built-in camera. I can't detect it in any application.

So far I have tried:

1. terminal killAll commands -> doesn't do anything and I get a 'No matching processes were found' message
2. Restart both SMC and PRAM
3. camera in safe mode also does not work
4. webcam on Secondary account does not work

I am at the end of my wits here.

Comment: Did you run the following command in terminal and rebooted your machine: sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant; sudo killall VDCAssistant

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware issue - the most likely of which is that the camera has failed.

The error message, "There is no connected camera" means that macOS cannot see it physically.  You can confirm this by looking at your System Report (from About This Mac) under both headings *Camera* and *USB*.  If you don't see anything there, the camera has failed.

You've already done excellent diagnostics by attempting to boot into Safe Mode and using a secondary account.  The fact that it's not found in Safe Mode means it's unfortunately non-functional.

You could have it repaired, but likely it will require a disassembly of or replacement of the display.  You might be better off using a "external" USB webcam as it will be far less expensive than fixing the built in one.